# how to view images from a local folder in php on apache server

Tags: php, html, apache

Im trying to create a simple website to run on my apache server and im trying to view images from a local folder in ubuntu but its not showing the images. below is a snippet of my code

```
for($i = $arr_bgn; $i < $arr_end; ++$i){
        // Add the images to the table cells
        echo '<td><img src="'; 
        echo '/home/Documents/'.$folder.'/'.$images[$i];
        echo '"/></td>'."\n";
    }
```

I dont know how to get around the local folder problem is there a way around this to make my php file work in apache?

If you needd to view the whole code feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

To access a file on the local file system you need to use the [File URI Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).  Otherwise the browser sees that as a server path and will try to fetch the file from the web server which served the page.

So instead of something like this:

```
<img src="/home/Documents/somefile.jpg" />
```

You'd want something like this:

```
<img src="file:///home/Documents/somefile.jpg" />
```

Comment: Hi i did try that but it still is not loading the image, it just shows a broken link, thanks

Comment: file:///home/Documents/2015_09_16/11-20150916112512-01.jpg thats the new file name but it still doesnt load

Comment: @the-bax: What does the browser's debugger say when it tries to load the file?  Are you sure the file exists on the local workstation?  Taking a step back, what is this meant to accomplish in the first place?  It's unusual for a webpage to try to show something on the local workstation, since a web server wouldn't know what's on the local workstation.

Comment: So im trying to look for images in a folder and then upload them onto a webpage, Ive managed to find the images and add them into a table in html. when i run the html file without the apache server they are shown. however when i add the php file in the var/www folder the images dont show

Comment: @the-bax: I don't think that approach makes much sense.  You won't be able to use server-side code to read the client-side file system, for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

try `file:///` before full path  as src eg

```
<img src="file:///C:/home/Documents/somefile.jpg" />
```